# How to change an element of a RecyclerView from one that is inside of it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a RecyclerView where I want to create something like the image below

In short: I want to disable a checked checkbox is activated, when another of the list is activated.

[image]

This my RecyclerView Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        /*Here I want to disable this on. I need to have a single enabled checkbox.*/

           //((CheckBox) holder.itemView.findViewById( )).setChecked(false);

       }
    });
}
```

As I can disable a CheckBox Checked this on. 
*Sorry for my English...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in coustructor method add this int variable :

```
int currentCheckedPosition = -1 ; // hold checked position
```

And in OnBindView() do this :

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder holder, final int position) {
 holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
             if(b){
                 currentCheckedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                 holder.checkbox.setChecked(b);
             } else {
                 currentCheckedPosition = - 1 ;
             } 
            notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    });

 holder.checkBox.setChecked(position == currentCheckedPosition);
}
```

Comment: I saw you rejected my edit. Nevermind, but I still have some doubt on your answer. For example, this if statement:
       ` if (currentCheckedPosition != - 1)` is never reached because currentCheckedPosition is changes value just inside. Moreover, if you don't add a `notifyDatasetChanged()` after the currentCheckedPosition updated, you could still see the check on the previously selected cell. Am I missing something? All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution but you could make a CompoundButton variable called currentlyChecked for the whole adapter. When onCheckedChange is fired, call

```
currentlyChecked.setChecked(false);
```

Hope this helps